# Hold on to vs hold onto

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between **hold on to** something and **hold onto** something?

The way I see it, they are absolutely identical in meaning.

Comment: In my experience as a native AmE speaker, **hold onto** has more of the connotation that you are actually on something unstable (or a moving vehicle), and that you should **hold onto** something for safety; whereas **hold on to** gives me the impression that there is something less massive than you, and you should **hold on to** it so that you do not lose control of it.

Comment: According to Ngram, **hold on to** is more widely used. If you look at actual instances, there is no obvious pattern to when you should use either form. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hold+on+to%2C+hold+onto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chold%20on%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chold%20onto%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I think @JavaLatte has the answer. It's _possible_ that some people will take one to mean "retain" or "keep hold of", and the other to mean "grab hold of", but I don't think it would be common, and I'm not sure which way round it would be.

Comment: @SteveES That makes me wonder too. I've noticed no difference whatever.

Comment: @SovereignSun I think the difference would be more obvious from the context than which form was used. I guess the only difference I would see would be from giving more emphasis to the "hold on" part. E.g. in an emphatic instruction "Hold on to the rail!" versus "I'm holding onto the rail."

Comment: These semantic distinctions are effectively spurious. See [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hold+on+to+the+rail%2Chold+onto+the+rail&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chold%20on%20to%20the%20rail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chold%20onto%20the%20rail%3B%2Cc0) chart (and *Hold on to / onto your dreams, Hold on to / onto the handle,* etc.) showing all that's happening is there's a ***general*** trend towards adopting the one-word form.

Comment: I would argue that **hold onto** is an incorrect, though very popular, usage.  *Onto <> on to.* As Java Latte says **hold on to** is more widely used (and it certainly makes more sense).  See similar posts for **log in to** vs **log into**.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular context, **hold onto** is technically incorrect because the verb is **to hold on**.

> Please hold on to the railing.

> Hold on to this package for me.

**onto** is a preposition on its own.

> The dog ran onto the patio after jumping into the pool.